# best way to display data after filling data in the form

Tags: android

can Anyone suggest me that...i have a form in that after entering all the fields user can view all the details before submiting so which technic is best way to diplay data i have limited fields max 15

Comment: there is no bast way. Everyone does as he thinks is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a AlertDialog or fragment with TextView to show all the typed data before submit, or you can also make a ReviewData Activity.